# Unattended-upgrades running for hours

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I often try to install packages and I cannot since `unattended-upgrades` has locked files.
Very often, it runs for more than 6 hours.
**Is that normal?**

Given I have

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades 
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic 
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
```

I guess that is unexpected.

PS: I have now changed configuration as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/831206/226614). Hopefully it will alleviate the issue.

**EDIT #1**:
This may indicate that it is actually waiting (due to network issues. most likely due to proxy blocking) and retrying, while keeping the lock.
I guess keeping the lock while just waiting is very unfortunate.

```
$ cat /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log | grep "2020-04-13"
2020-04-13 06:10:49,892 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2020-04-13 06:10:49,894 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2020-04-13 06:10:49,894 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2020-04-13 06:10:49,895 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic
2020-04-13 06:25:16,404 WARNING package libpython2.7 upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2020-04-13 06:25:21,128 WARNING package libpython2.7 upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2020-04-13 06:46:57,101 WARNING package libpython2.7-dev upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2020-04-13 06:47:02,113 WARNING package libpython2.7-dev upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2020-04-13 08:29:08,908 ERROR An error occurred: 403  URLBlockDownload [IP: XXXXXXXX]
2020-04-13 08:29:08,909 ERROR The URI http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/db5.3/libdb5.3-java_5.3.28-13.1ubuntu1.1_all.deb failed to download, aborting
2020-04-13 08:29:24,965 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2020-04-13 08:29:24,966 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2020-04-13 08:29:24,966 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2020-04-13 08:29:24,967 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic
2020-04-13 08:43:57,555 WARNING package libpython2.7 upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2020-04-13 08:44:02,297 WARNING package libpython2.7 upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2020-04-13 09:05:46,548 WARNING package libpython2.7-dev upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
2020-04-13 09:05:51,561 WARNING package libpython2.7-dev upgradable but fails to be marked for upgrade (E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
```

As for the other issue/s, I did not find yet the cause, but
I have updated `libpython2.7` and `libpython2.7-dev` to see if this removes some of the retrying and delays.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpython2.7
...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python2.7-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal
...
```

---

On a quick test, I could not get network speed, but it is usually not an issue

```
$ speedtest-cli --no-upload
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Cannot retrieve speedtest configuration
ERROR: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

Related:
[Limiting the time Unattended-Upgrade keeps the lock on `/var/lib/dpkg/`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226837/limiting-the-time-unattended-upgrade-keeps-the-lock-on-var-lib-dpkg)

Comment: It running for 6h is really unusual unless one has an incredibly slow net speed or bad mirror.

Comment: What are the results of running `speedtest-cli --no-upload` command from the terminal?

Comment: @DKBose - Please see edited OP.

Comment: @karel - Please see edited OP.

Comment: Suggestion: You have held broken packages. Fix that first. After that, start looking at those network access failures. Disable unattended-upgrades until your system is ready to use it.

Comment: @user535733 - I guess I have no more broken packages. Is there any way to check this to get a definite answer?

Comment: You can test apt function by running an ordinary `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, followed by a test install (`sudo apt install hello`) and removal (`sudo apt autoremove hello`)